# Как получить float скинов в торговой площадки steam?

Tags: node.js, парсер, steam, веб-скрейпинг

Я хочу создать бота который будет находить скины (с указаными флотами и стикерами) и отправлять это пользователю. Пишу бота на NodeJS.
Начальную цену, цену лота, название предмета, его изображение получить было просто с помощью веб-скрапинга.
Но возникли проблемы при получении float предмета, так как этих данных нет на странице предметов (без специальных расширений для браузера SIH и CSFloat). Какие есть варианты чтобы получить эти данные?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]